# Eclipse J2E: IndexNotFoundException[no such index]

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch

I have create a java client to connect to elasticsearch and request a document in several indexes called analytics-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}. Here is my code:

```
try {
    client = TransportClient.builder().build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddr), serverPort));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("analytics*", "logs", "AVbgot3mAQOAFbgN9Rtz")
        .setOperationThreaded(false)
        .get();
```

However, I got the following error: [analytics*] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]

It works when I try with: 'analytics-2016.08.31' . However, for my purpose I need to request on multiple indexes.

Do you know how I can solve that ?

Thank you fopr your attention and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the index name, then you can't run a GET by ID which supposes you know `index/type/id` but you need to search across multiple indices.

You can have a look at [IDs query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-ids-query.html) and [its Java form](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.3/java-term-level-queries.html).